# Groovy - Simple way to see if set of objects has a property that contains a value

Tags: groovy

Is there a simple way to check if a set of objects contains property with a value?

Example of something like I'm looking for:

`[[name:'a'],[name:'b'],[name:'c']].toSet().contains{it->it.name=='b'} == true`

EDIT: I came up with a solution, but if someone has a more efficient one that perhaps doesn't create a new collection, please share it.

`[[name:'a'],[name:'b'],[name:'c']].toSet().findAll{it.name=='b'}.size()>0`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[[name: 'a'], [name: 'b'], [name: 'c']].any{ it.name == 'b' }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def x1 = [['name':'a'],['name':'b'],['name':'c']]
def x2 = x1.​groupBy{it.name}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
x2.containsKey('b')​​​​
```

This should work for you.

Comment: I created a list of maps and then transformed the list into a set to create an example set.

Comment: @Anonymous1 - Check this out.